# Add value to vector on specific index

Tags: clojure

i have a function that subdivide a line between a list of points.

```
(defn subdivide [points]

  (vec 

   (for [i (range (count points))]
     (let [A (nth points i)
           C (nth points (mod (inc i) (count points)))

           x (/ (+ (first A) (first C)) 2)
           y (/ (+ (second A) (second C)) 2)]

          [x y] ))
   ))
```

currently my return value is a list of the new x and y positions. how can i return a list with all positions. x/y from A, the new x/y and x/y from C? so i want to inject the new x/y in the position vector between A und C. but how could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can map every edge with index `i` to a pair of points: the starting point of the edge and its midpoint. Then you concatenate the result. There is a special function for mapping and concatenation, [mapcat](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapcat). But keeping the `for`-macro of your original code sample and then concatenating the result into a lazy sequence using `(apply concat ...` or into a vector using `(into [] cat ...` would probably work too.

```
(defn subdivide [points]
  (mapcat (fn [i]
            (let [A (nth points i)
                  C (nth points (mod (inc i) (count points)))

                  x (/ (+ (first A) (first C)) 2)
                  y (/ (+ (second A) (second C)) 2)]

              [A [x y]]))
          (range (count points))))

(subdivide [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1]])
;; => ([0 0] [1/2 0] [1 0] [1/2 1/2] [0 1] [0 1/2])
```

**Note:** This code subdivides the points assuming they form a cycle with an edge from the last to the first point. The code, however, wouldn't look that different if this were not the case.

**Note 2:** There could maybe be hidden performance issues of linear search of using `nth` on some lazy sequences, not sure though. But on vectors, it should be fine.

Comment: thx, this was very helpful. and how can run the "mapcat thing" in a loop with 5 iterations to generate more and more points between the new and existing points?

Comment: @MrD I think you can just call `(iterate subdivide [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1]])` to generate a lazy sequence of applying subdivide to `[[0 0] [1 0] [0 1]]`, then to the result (`(subdivide (subdivide [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1]]))`), and so so. To get the nth value call `(nth (iterate subdivide [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1]]) 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does the hard part. To put the new intermediate values "between" the existing values there's a library function which can be used - [interleave](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interleave):

So we take your function:

```
(defn subdivide [points]
  (vec (for [i (range (count points))]
         (let [A (nth points i)
               C (nth points (mod (inc i) (count points)))
               x (/ (+ (first A) (first C)) 2)
               y (/ (+ (second A) (second C)) 2)]
           [x y] ))))
```

or we can use one based on the library function `partition`:

```
(defn subdivide [points]
  (mapv #(conj []
               (/ (+ (first (first %)) (first (second %))) 2)
               (/ (+ (second (first %)) (second (second %))) 2))
        (partition 2 1 (conj (vec points) (first points)))))
```

and then create a function to interleave the input points with the vector of intermediate points:

```
(defn subdivide-and-interleave [points]
  (butlast (interleave points (subdivide points))))
```

I think it's best to define `subdivide-and-interleave` as a separate function - that way you can invoke the `subdivide` function separately if you find it's needed.

Note that here we're dropping the last element produced by the `subdivide` call, which represents the intermediate point between the last and first elements of the `points` vector. If you want this to be included in the result you can drop the `butlast` invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach the problem using my favorite [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Be sure to peruse the [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) and especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn interpolate-vals
  [vals]
  (let-spy
    [val-pairs         (partition 2 1 vals)
     mid-vals          (mapv
                         (fn [[a b]] (* 0.5 (+ a b))) ; destructure pair into values & compute avg
                         val-pairs)
     mid-vals-sentinal (cons :dummy mid-vals) ; add a dummy element at front
     result-sentinal   (interleave mid-vals-sentinal vals)
     result            (vec (rest result-sentinal))]
    result))

(dotest
  (is= (interpolate-vals (range 5))
    [0  0.5  1  1.5  2  2.5  3  3.5  4]))
```

The `let-spy` shows the intermediate results:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 15
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
val-pairs   => ((0 1) (1 2) (2 3) (3 4))
mid-vals     => [0.5   1.5   2.5   3.5]
mid-vals-sentinal   => (:dummy   0.5   1.5   2.5   3.5)
result-sentinal     => (:dummy 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4)
result => [0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4]

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

You can use the same technique to computer the mid-point of each pair of points, then construct a new output vector.

---

### Alternate answer:

If you want to use a more imperative style, you could also use the [insert-at](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#inserting-values-into-a-sequence)  function from the Tupelo library:

```
(s/defn insert-at :- ts/List
  "Inserts an element into a collection at the specified index."
  [coll     :- ts/List
   index    :- s/Int
   elem     :- s/Any]
  ...)

(is (= [9 0 1] (insert-at [0 1] 0 9)))
(is (= [0 9 1] (insert-at [0 1] 1 9)))
(is (= [0 1 9] (insert-at [0 1] 2 9)))
```

However, this would be slower for large sequences just as inserting into the middle of a `List` in Java.